How to edit image by Dall e api in android
how to i can edit a guiding by a text by dall e api in android
by this when i make request it showing

Failed with error code 400

@Multipart
@POST("v1/images/edits")
suspend fun createImageEdit(
    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Query("prompt") prompt: String,
    @Query("n") n: Int,
    @Query("size") size: String
): Response<ImageData>

What is the issue?
